# Need to parse JAVA source code

Tags: java, parsing, ms-word, javaparser

I need to parse MANY JAVA files and save the class names and methods in a word(.docx) file with certain formatting(certain words need to be bolded/indented etc.). 
Are there any good tools or libraries that I can use for the same? Thanks!

Comment: ["Java Parser" Google Search Results](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=java%20parser)

Answer (score 0):

[java.lang.reflect](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html) for getting class names and method names.

[java.io.FileOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) for writing into file.

[java.awt.Font](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html) for making certain characters bold/indeted.

Comment: None of this has any direct applicability to the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using JavaParser for extracting all the information you need from Java code. It is a mature product with a reasonably large community and can get the work done.

https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser